# LPTHW:Ex48 Unit test(using nosetests), Classes,method arguments TypeErrors

Tags: python

I am Newbie working through LPTHW [This is the link for it](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html). At ex48 I am given a lot of code as unit tests to which I am supposed to write the corresponding my_code which will be tested(using nosetests, sorry lots of tests in this sentence.)

this is my_code:

```
class lexicon(object):

    def __init__(self):
    #some initial stuff.

    def scan(self,stuff):
    #some cool code.
```

And this is the test.py file

```
from nose.tools import*
from Ex48.code import lexicon

def test_directions():    

    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    ...#Unimportant details the above is enough.
```

However when I run nosetests I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\python31\lib\site-packages\nose'case.py", line 197, i runTest
    ... line x, in test_directions
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
TypeError: scan() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

Which is odd because one of those 2 arguments is the self one and I thought it should not be given.

To remedy this problem I have tried:

```
@staticmethod
def scan(self,stuff):
```

But this gave me the same typeError

Next I tried:

```
assert_equal(lexicon.__init__(self).scan(...)
```

But this didn't work either(I think .****init****(self) should be used in another class than lexicon only, not in main).

I Finally resolved to:

```
lexicon1=lexicon()
def test_directions():    
    assert_equal(lexicon1.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
```

But this is not how the exercise is supposed to be done!

P.S: I did not include the whole traceback because it might not be necessary(and it's getting very late). I did not include parts of my code bc I'm sure that it works fine and is not causing the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you're doing it (making an instance and then using its method--your example with lexicon1) is good, right?

If you want to do it the first way, have you tried:

```
@classmethod
def scan(self, stuff):
```

I'm a newbie too (just finished exercise 49), so maybe someone else can answer better.  Curious, though, whether @classmethod decorator does what you want.

Comment: Yep! That actually worked now I don't need to create an instance!But apparently @classmethod ignores everything(as in all attributes,dicts lists etc) in def __init__(self): so I had to copy paste them to my scan function definition.

Comment: I don't know! I think I prefer creating an instance than this.

Comment: However @Steve Koch do you know if I should replace the self argument in scan with cls and then do so for the rest of that method?

Comment: Sorry, that's about the extent of my knowledge so far :)  Thanks for trying it out and posting your results!